# TCPDF failing with Connection Reset error

Tags: php, apache, tcpdf

I'm using `TCPDF` to generate a fairly large document. This document can have upwards of 1000 images (each between 20KB-50KB) embedded within it.

It works great (if a little slowly) up until about 800 images, where the browser returns a `Connection Reset error` and stops loading.

I've checked all the usual suspects, `PHP max execution time`, `memory limits`, `Apache execution time`, all to no avail. I'm not getting any errors in any log files to help my further diagnose this.

Am I missing something? Anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks

Comment: call the script from the command line not a browser

Comment: wget just tells me the same thing (Connection reset by peer)

Comment: who said wget, that's just another browser interface. use the php cli